# node.js debug fails when setting breakpoint in script not yet loaded?

Tags: node.js, debugging, npm

I've been using node's simple command-line debugger for various unit tests for quite a while, with no problem. *(Edit: not node-inspector, just plain old cmdline `node debug <scriptname>`, not even using a browser.)* Something went wrong the other day, and now it doesn't work any more: it goes dormant when I try to set a breakpoint in a script that hasn't yet loaded.

It works fine when I set a breakpoint in a script that's already loaded (the script I entered on the command line with `node debug <scriptname>`) -- I can say `sb(74)` or `sb(<scriptname>, 74`) and it works fine, as it always has. But when I set a breakpoint for a script not already loaded yet, the debugger just stops working completely. I try `c` to continue, or `n` for next, and nothing happens at all: no stopping at a breakpoint, and in fact, no prompt at all. Like the debugger has gone to sleep completely.

I can't remember how the output used to look on startup, but this seems a little strange:

```
< Debugger listening on [::]:5858
connecting to 127.0.0.1:5858 ... ok
```

I never looked at it before, but it seems like it would have something other than `::` in between the `[]`. Maybe that's a clue?

I've uninstalled and reinstalled both node and npm multiple times; I even uninstalled and reinstalled homebrew and redid all of it from scratch. No joy.

- Homebrew 1.0.6
- Node v6.7.0
- npm 3.10.7

Comment: Is it possible that you 've updated node into a newer version?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I have reinstalled it a couple of times and now I have 6.7.0

Comment: I assume that you are using node-inspector. Sometimes there are some incompatibilities between the node version and the node-inspector version. I would suggest removing node-inspector and installing it again.

Comment: No, just straight command-line node debugger: `node debug <scriptname>`. Not connecting to the browser or anything, just unit-testing scripts from the command line

Comment: Oops, sorry then, wrong assumption :)